# Script exiting on failed nosetests

Tags: bash

I am using a small script to merge current branch into the trunk and push it out. How can I make the script fail if nosetests fails?

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout $1
nosetests
git checkout master
git merge $1
git push
git checkout $1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `set -e` after the shebang line to make the script exit if any of the command fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
git checkout $1
nosetests
```

From `help set`:

> -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout $1
nosetests || exit 1
git checkout master
git merge $1
git push
git checkout $1
```

The `||` will check the return code of `nosetests` and will execute the command `exit 1` if it is non-zero.

Another variant could be.

```
#!/bin/bash
git checkout $1
if ! nosetests
then
    exit 1
fi
git checkout master
git merge $1
git push
git checkout $1
```